# Where can I get Log Caching in Subversion for free?

Tags: svn, caching

Is there a free, open source solution to the fact that vanilla subversion does not do log caching? I really just want to use svn as is, except that I hate waiting for it to download the log entries.

Answer (score 3):

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) does log caching.

Answer (score 1):

The free Foundation version of [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com) has a local Log Cache (though not open-source).